# If option works but else if does not

Tags: java

i have a method i am working on, its part of a larger program but i think the code i posted will be enough.

When i select option 1 in my menu, it works as it should, but when i select option 2 , it just ends the program. can anybody spot the issue?

Resolved : the choice == 1 should be 2.

Can i also add to this question, would it be best to put the in putted data into an array, if so, should i declare the array in the main class,superclass or the Sub class

```
static void addBook(){
            String title,author;
            int choice;
            boolean onLoan;
            loanbook book1; // TESTING ONLY
            System.out.print("Press 1 for Fiction or 2 for Non Fiction: ");  // sub menu for fiction and non fiction
            choice = keyboard.nextInt();
            if (choice == 1){

                System.out.println("Please enter book title: ");
                title = keyboard.nextLine();
                title = keyboard.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Please enter book author: ");
                author = keyboard.nextLine();
                onLoan = false; // not used yet
                book1 = new fiction(title,author);
                System.out.println(book1.toString());
        }
            else if (choice == 1) {
                System.out.println("Please enter book title: ");
                title = keyboard.nextLine();
                title = keyboard.nextLine();                ;
                System.out.println("Please enter book author: ");
                author = keyboard.nextLine();
                onLoan = false; // not used yet
                book1 = new nonfiction(title,author);
                System.out.println(book1.toString());
            }

        }
```

Comment: Maybe use `else if (choice == 2) {`...

Comment: Such a simple thing, good spot. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `if` and the `else if` both uses the same value to compare. You should define a constant for the values or enum. You can then write your code as follows:

```
System.out.println("Please enter book title: ");
title = keyboard.nextLine();
title = keyboard.nextLine();
System.out.println("Please enter book author: ");
author = keyboard.nextLine();
onLoan = false; // not used yet
if (choice == 1) { // Use constant or enum here
    book1 = new fiction(title,author);
    System.out.println(book1.toString());
}
else if (choice == 2) { // Use constant or enum here
   book1 = new nonfiction(title,author);
   System.out.println(book1.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You wrote: `if (x == 1) { } else if (x == 1) {}`

If `choice` is equal to `1`, you can never get into the the else part. From the other side, if you are in the else body, `choice` can't match `1`, because you know it is not equal to `1`, because of the fact you got in the else part due to the fact that the first condition was false.

Answer (score 0):

You check for `choice == 1` in both parts of the if.